# spring タグが２つの対象(spring@rails, spring@java) を表している

Tags: 討議, タグ

現状、 [spring](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) タグは、java における [spring](https://spring.io/) と、rails における [spring](https://github.com/rails/spring) の両方にタグ付けされています。

これは、正しいタグ付けではないと感じているのですが、どのように対応したらよいのでしょうか。

NOTE: 本家SO では、 rails の方を [spring-gem](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/spring-gem) であったり、 [rails-spring](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rails-spring) であったりとタグ付けしているようです。(ただ、[この質問](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381568/trouble-starting-rails-application)のように、依然と spring タグを利用しているものも、それなりに存在している様子です)

追記: たとえば、本家にならって、 rails の方の spring のタグを、 rails-spring に直すように私が編集して回っても(といっても、２件のみのようですが) いいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

同じspringという名前でもJavaのフレームワークとRailsのgemでまったく別物であり、興味をもつユーザ層も分かれると思いますのでタグを分離する方向に賛成です。
いったん分離してしまえばタグを付ける際にサジェスチョンが出るので、今後混同する人も減ることが期待できるのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2):

むしろ本家SOだとRailsのSpringにはあまりタグを付けないように見えます。

- [`spring -java [rails] -[spring] -[spring-gem] -[rails-spring]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion%20spring%20-java%20%5Brails%5D%20-%5Bspring%5D%20-%5Bspring-gem%5D%20-%5Brails-spring%5D) 624件
- [`-java [rails] ( [spring] or [spring-gem] or [rails-spring] )`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+-java+%5Brails%5D+%28+%5Bspring%5D+or+%5Bspring-gem%5D+or+%5Brails-spring%5D+%29) 49件

現在日本語版に投稿されている以下の質問も、Rails全般の話と言えるのであれば、あえて spring タグを付けなくてもいいのかなと思いましたが、いかがでしょうか。
<sub>（Rails使いではないので適当なこと言ってたらすみません）</sub>

- [一定時間アイドル状態になっているSpringを自動停止させたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/5616/8000)
- [lib/spring/application.rb:248:in `start_with?': incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8 (Encoding::CompatibilityError)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/11513/8000)

Comment: ２つあるうちの後者は、spring の話というより rails 全般の話のように見受けられます。なのでむしろ、 タグを spring から ruby-on-rails に変更した方がよいのではないか、と (改めて中身を見た結果) 感じました。

ただ前者は、 rails の中でも特に spring についての質問のように見受けられます。

Answer (score 1):

タグを作成するには[150信用度](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)が必要。

タグを作成してから（個人の意見は英語版と同じく[spring-gem](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-gem)と[rails-spring](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-spring)でいいと思っていますが）、[spring](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring)を存在している質問を全部どっちかに編集されたらいいです。[spring](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring)の質問が少なくなったら、[spring-gem](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-gem)か[rails-spring](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rails-spring)の多い方の別名にしますので、[spring](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring)が付けられなくなります。

どうですか？

Comment: 本家SO においては、 spring-gem と rails-spring は同じ対象(rails にて利用されている spring) を指し示している様子です。英語版に合わせるのであれば、java のものを spring にして、 rails のものを rails-spring にするのがいいのではないか、と考えています。

Comment: @YukiInoue それでもいいです。皆様がrails関係のタグを「rails-spring」にすれば、同じようなことができます。